# How to get recorded dates and not recorded days in database in sql

Tags: mysql

I wrote a query to get two days between all days in the database but my requirement is to get recorded dates and not recorded days in the database. now this query output is only recorded dates in the database. I need to get all days, between two dates

my query is

```
SELECT COUNT(activity_detail.activity_type_config_id) As count,
user_det.full_name, DATEPART(day, activity_detail.created_date) AS day,
DATEPART(month, activity_detail.created_date) AS month,
DATEPART(year, activity_detail.created_date) AS year
FROM activity_detail activity_detail,activity_type_config activity_type_config,activity_user user_det 
WHERE activity_detail.activity_type_config_id = activity_type_config.activity_type_config_id and user_det.activity_user_id = activity_detail.activity_user_id
AND activity_detail.created_date BETWEEN '2021-01-08 10:18:13' AND '2021-11-17 10:40:09' 
GROUP BY user_det.full_name,DATEPART(month, activity_detail.created_date),DATEPART(day, activity_detail.created_date),DATEPART(year, activity_detail.created_date)
ORDER BY DATEPART(year, activity_detail.created_date) ASC, DATEPART(month, activity_detail.created_date) ASC,DATEPART(day, activity_detail.created_date)
```

Output

```
count name day month year
1   john1   8   8    2021
1   carter  11  8   2021
1   john1   15  9   2021
4   john1   18  9   2021
7   carter  18  9   2021
1   john1   19  9   2021
2   carter  19  9   2021
3   john1   20  9   2021
42  carter21    9   2021
1   john1   21  9   2021
```

i need output

```
count name day month year
0   null    1   8    2021
0   null    2   8   2021...
1   john1   8   8    2021
1   carter  11  8   2021
0   null    1   9   2021
0   null    2   9   2021
0   null    3   9   2021...
1   john1   15  9   2021
4   john1   18  9   2021
7   carter  18  9   2021
1   john1   19  9   2021
2   carter  19  9   2021
3   john1   20  9   2021
0   null  16    11  2021
0   null    17  11  2021
```

not recorded days result must be 0,null but these are not in the database.
help to get the all dates.

Answer (score 1):

It will be something like (not debugged)

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
nums AS ( SELECT 1 num
          UNION ALL
          SELECT num + 1 FROM nums WHERE num < 31 ),
ranges AS ( SELECT MIN(day) day, month, year
            FROM table
            GROUP BY 2,3 )
data AS ( {your query text} ) 
SELECT count, name, day, month, year
FROM data
UNION ALL
SELECT 0, NULL, nums.num, ranges.month, ranges.year
FROM nums
JOIN ranges ON nums.num < ranges.day
```